Auto Rig Pro, Export Scripting from documentation gives me an error
Blender 4.0.1
Auto Rig Pro 3.69.28
When I copy and paste any of the script examples from the documentation: https://lucky3d.fr/auto-rig-pro/doc/ge_export_doc.html
I get the error:

AttributeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.arp.arp_export_fbx_panel"
error, could not be found

Here is one example of a script that'll get the error:
import bpy
import os

# set the file path output here
file_output = "F:\\MyExportFbx.fbx"

# set some settings...
scn = bpy.context.scene
scn.arp_export_rig_type = 'UNIVERSAL'
# types: 'humanoid' for humanoid characters, 'mped' for universal skeletons

scn.arp_engine_type = 'UNREAL'
# other useful settings
scn.arp_keep_bend_bones = True
scn.arp_units_x100 = True

# run export
bpy.ops.arp.arp_export_fbx_panel(filepath=file_output)


Auto Rig Pro is a third-party addon which we can't help with here. However, I'd suspect that the examples you've found were written for an earlier version of Blender as some of the APIs changed between versions 3 and 4 of Blender. Suggest you contact the developers of the addon.
